# Session Timeouts despite pinging

Tags: jquery, asp.net, timeout

I have an ASP.NET web site.

I am updating an image on my page via a timer (every 10 seconds) and I call an ashx page to get the stream.

This part works OK.

I have a session time-out configured in my IIS for 15 minutes.

I want to keep the session alive.

All examples I have looked at look the same. They basically 'ping' a page.

I am essentially doing this when I refresh my image.

Yet, the page times out after 15 minutes.

I can post my code but it is very simple.

I just like to know why my session times out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your session configuration section from web.config? By default session is increasing after each session access. So, if you access session in your ashx service, then timeout should be also shifted to new 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  There is no session sessting in my web config. it is being handled by IIS?